# Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9. Return 0 for no numbers

Tags: python

```
def summer_69(arr):
    for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
        if arr[i] == range (6,10):
            del arr[i]
        elif arr[i] != range(6,10):
            return arr[i] + arr[i + 1]

print(summer_69([1,3,5]))
```

When I print it out it prints 4 for some reason instead of 9? I am a beginner so sorry if my code is slobby. Basicially the problem is asking for us to give them the sum but ignore the numbers 6 through 9. Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong and is there like an easier way to do this?

Comment: `if arr[i] in range(6,10): # don't use; else: # use`

Comment: `for i in range(0,len(arr))` - otherwise you'll skip the last element in the array.   `range(a,b)` is everything from `[a,b)` not `[a,b]`

Comment: @selbie I think that's intentional, because it later uses `arr[i+1]`, and that would be out of range when you get to the last `i`.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the list that you're iterating over. When you delete an element, the indexes of all the following elements shift down, and you'll skips some of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not skipping the section of numbers starting with `6` and ending with `9`, you're just skipping any numbers between `6` and `9`.

You can use a flag variable to indicate when you're in this section.

You're also not summing all the numbers. You're returning as soon as you find a number that's not in the range, and just adding that number and the next number.

```
def summer_69(arr):
    in_69 = False
    total = 0
    for num in arr:
        if in_69:
            if num == 9:
                in_69 = False
        elif num == 6:
            in_69 = True
        else:
            total += num
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional programming. array object has `map() and reduce()` methods

```
var a = [1, 3,5];
var r = a.filter((e)=>e < 6 ||e > 9).reduce((prev, e) => prev + e);
console.log(r);
```

- `a.filter((e)=>e < 6 ||e > 9))` this filters the numbers that are not in the range (6, 9) and return an array of numbers that are not in the range(6,9)
- `.reduce((prev, e) => prev + e)` this will iteratively adds each number and return a single value.

Answer (score 0):

cleaner solution using a set for lookup:

```
def s69(arr):
if len(arr) == 0:
    return 0
out = 0
d = {6,7,8,9}
for a in arr:
    if a not in d:
        out+=a
return out
```